# How can I use files in my Android application written in Rust?

Tags: android, rust, assets

I'd like to have additional assets shipped with my Android application, which I'm programming in Rust (using `cargo apk` from [android-rs-glue](https://github.com/tomaka/android-rs-glue)).

How can I access a directory

- with files which will be placed there during the installation
- which is optimally local to the application (isn't there some "data" directory)
- or achieve something similar where I can read a file (for example say a `.obj` file with some game models) without embedding these files into the source code

?

Comment: Know nothing of Rust but i would think at develop time you would put the files in the assets directory. And at run time read them from there. It is unclear if you manage the first part already.

Comment: @greenapps Unfortunately, there is no `assets` directory when programming in Rust.

Comment: @torkleyy There's an asset folder for anything in Android.  If there isn't, you'll need to fix android-rs-glue.  Its a build concept, not a language concept.

Comment: But notice even their examples have an assets directory.  That's how you do it.

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes there somehow is an `assets` directory; I've seen it in [this example](https://github.com/tomaka/android-rs-glue/tree/master/examples/use_assets), the problem is just that there is no path which points at it (or I don't know about it) and I have to specify a path to the file because of the library API I'm using. I can only get the bytes of the file...

Comment: Well in Android asset files aren't actually files-  they're part of the apk.  You can't reference them as files.  Your best bet is to copy them to disk first, and then you know the path.

Comment: @GabeSechan Seems like a pretty dirty workaround. If this is the only way I'll try to extend the API. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @torkleyy Its a pretty common pattern in Java Android, especially if the contents either go to a 3rd party library that takes a file or they re updatable over the web (in which case the update has to be on disk, so may as well write the original there and reduce code paths).  The other option is to write a File abstraction for the assets directory, but I think that's going to be really hard to do if you don't have direct access to AssetManager on the Java api.